# Twilio MMS settings to affect carrier compression of video?

Tags: twilio

Does Twilio have any settings that affect a mobile carrier or phone's compression of MMS messages? I'm texting videos to a Twilio number and the compression is high, such that the video once received displays in poor poor quality when viewed in a browser when scale is expanded (such as full screen). Same video emailed and viewed in browser displays with high quality (not compressed). The carrier in this case is Verizon. The phone is an iPhone 11. The content type is coming in as video/3gpp. Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

It is being compressed on the carrier side, there is nothing you can set on Twilio to change this behavior. You may be able to reduce the size of the video/transcode the video before you send it, but it will be to be extremely compressed, 600KB or less.

You are better off using [WhatsApp](https://www.twilio.com/changelog/send-media-message-16mb-size-twilio-api-whatsapp), which allows sending video attachments up to 16MB.